# Posición de MenuContextual en Pyqt

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

quisiera saber como posicionar el menu que genere, debajo del boton abrir.

este es mi codigo:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAction, QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QPushButton, QMenuBar

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.boton = QPushButton('Abrir',self)
        self.boton.setStyleSheet('Background-color:grey;')
        self.boton1 = QPushButton('Edicion',self)
        self.boton1.setStyleSheet('Background-color:grey;')
        self.boton1.setGeometry(100,0,100,30)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.menu)

    def menu(self): # Este es el menu

        menu = QMenu(self)
        nuevo = menu.addMenu('Archivo')
        nuevo.addMenu('Nuevo')
        menu.exec_()


app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

Como se ve en la imagen el menu aparece fuera de la ventana y quiero que aparezca debajo del boton. como si fuera un menubar()

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes posicionar el menú usando el método [`exec`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmenu.html#exec-1) y [`mapToGlobal`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mapToGlobal) para trasladar las coordenadas del vértice inferior izquierdo de tu widget `boton` a coordenadas de la ventana principal:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMenu, QPushButton

class Principal(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.boton = QPushButton('Abrir',self)
        self.boton.setStyleSheet('Background-color:grey;')
        self.boton1 = QPushButton('Edicion',self)
        self.boton1.setStyleSheet('Background-color:grey;')
        self.boton1.setGeometry(100,0,100,30)
        self.boton.clicked.connect(self.menu)

    def menu(self):
        menu = QMenu(self)
        nuevo = menu.addMenu('Archivo')
        nuevo.addMenu('Nuevo')
        menu.exec_(self.boton.mapToGlobal(QPoint(0, self.boton.geometry().bottom())))



app = QApplication([])
p = Principal()
p.show()
app.exec_()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas Gracias FJSevilla me sirvio mucho

Comment: FJSevilla conoceras alguna manera de cambair la posicion de los botones de menu que se agragan en el MenuBar().